# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'SurveySettingTypes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to have a obj like this:

```
type SurveySettingTypes = {
  validity_period?: string 
  validity_start_time?: string
  validity_end_time?: string 
}
```

```
    let initSettingData: SurveySettingTypes = {}
    Object.keys(survey).forEach(row => {
      if (settingDataKeys.includes(row)) {
        // Err: No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'SurveySettingTypes'
        initSettingData[row] = survey[row]
      }
    })
```

But if I write like this

```
type SurveySettingTypes = {
  [key: string]:{
  validity_period?: string 
  validity_start_time?: string
  validity_end_time?: string }
}
```

I get value as

```
   let initSettingData: {[key: string] :SurveySettingTypes} = {}
   
   initSettingData.editor_validity_period_switch = true // Err: Type 'true' has no properties in common with type 'SurveySettingTypes'
```

what should I do? help me and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys` returns an array of `string`. It does not guarantee that the strings would exactly match the keys of `SurveySettingTypes`, hence the warning. You need to explicitly guarantee that the string array coming from `Object.keys` are indeed the keys of `SurveySettingTypes`. You can do something like this:

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/qNBGkm)

```ts
type SurveySettingTypes = {
  validity_period?: string ;
  validity_start_time?: string;
  validity_end_time?: string ;
}

const survey: Record<string, string> = {
  validity_period: 'wqwe',
  validity_start_time: 'wewe',
  validity_end_time: 'wewewe'
}

const settingDataKeys = ['validity_period', 'validity_start_time'];

let initSettingData: SurveySettingTypes = {}
Object.keys(survey).forEach(row => {
    if (settingDataKeys.includes(row)) {
    // Guarantee the row is type of SurveySettingTypes's key
    initSettingData[row as keyof SurveySettingTypes] = survey[row]
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, but my vscode has a erro<br/>                                  
`Object.keys(survey).forEach(row => {
    if (settingDataKeys.includes(row)) {
    // (parameter) row: string
Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
    initSettingData[row as keyof SurveySettingTypes] = survey[row]
    }
});`

Comment: @sanheart Could you post a [complete, minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on TS Playground? As far as I think, this should solve the issue: `initSettingData[row as keyof SurveySettingTypes] = survey[row] as string`